# Share string resource files between C# application and php application

Tags: c#, php, web-applications, resx, resource-files

As part of a project I am working on we are designing a web application that contains two components. The first component is an application written in C# that runs on a client's PC and pushes information to a web server. The second component is a web application written in php that runs on the web server so the client can remotely view the data pushed by the C# application.

My question is, what would be the best way to go about sharing the string resource files between both applications? We desire this behavior because many terms appear across both the c# application and the user interface of the web page.

Comment: for this scenario I'd either store all in database or have both apps sharing error codes having the resource file use the error code as the key for the strings.